# preserve formatting in lexical editor

Tags: lexicaljs

Whenever im trying to copy-paste text from word doc or google doc to lexical editor, formatting is not preserved. Is there any api provided by lexical to preserve formatting.

How to preserve formatting in editor?

I tried many ways didn't worked out

I solved this , using [https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization#handling-extended-html-styling]